# Full size page background image ignore margins

Tags: python, html, css, pdf-generation, weasyprint

I am trying to create a PDF via the python weasyprint library HTML converter. I want to use a full page background image (svg) that contains the headers/footers and overlay content on top of them.

The issue is regarding page breaks... In order for the image to be full size I set the @page margin to 0, but then of course the page doesn't break until the very bottom. If I set the margins to a decent page break distance I then can't get the image to be full page size disregarding the margins.

Is there a way to circumvent this problem or is the idea doomed to failure

Comment: I might be missing something and am not familiar with WeasyPrint, but would applying a padding to the body of the page not work?

Comment: In addition to the margin, you should account for the bleed as well (crop doesn't add any space).  I'm struggling with the same question and haven't found a solid answer yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<style>
image
{
margin: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see your problem, but if you want a background image that covers the full window, you could set it to the body and make the body's min-width and min-height to 100vw and 100vh like so:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("YOUR_IMG_URL");
  background-size: contain; /*or cover or whatever you like*/
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
  </head>
  
  <body>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: If you are asking something else, please explain your question with code examples

Comment: This will not work, as there is no "window" to cover.  Weasyprint does not have a viewport, and thus no vw or vh.  It uses the (lesser known, as it is generally for print) W3C Paged Media model and @page, not a viewport and the Continuous Model.  For instance, there is also a print bleed area in addition to the margin, and :left and :right selectors for pages.  For more see https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/